# How to call a function by loading a string in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I'm testing, In case I have my posts.html templete and I wanted to load all posts in a summarized form on the page, however one side would load the posts with even id and the other with odd id.

I did a function in views.py and wanted to load all posts in posts.html.

```
def posted(request):
    posts = Album.objects.all()
    for post in posts:
        if post % 2 == 0:
            return render(request, """<div class="container marketing  ">
<div class="row mb-2 " >
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row g-0 border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">{{ post.title }}</strong>
          <h3 class="mb-0">{{ post.author.get_full_name }}</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ post.created_at|date:'d, M Y'}}</div>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{ post.summary|safe }}</p>
          <a href="/post/{{ post.pk }}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
          <img class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" src="{{post.image.url}}" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/></img>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>""",)
        return render(request, """<div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row g-0 border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-success">Design</strong>
          <h3 class="mb-0">Post title</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 11</div>
          <p class="mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
          <img class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" src="{% static "images/pexels-pixabay-159358.jpg"%}" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/></img>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>""")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on its current behaviour? How far did you get with your efforts?
Can you call the `%` operator on post objects or did you want to use their IDs?

Comment: I did it below and it works, but the block on the left brings the same content on the right.

{% for post in posts %}
   block 1 - with {{ post. title }}
   block 2 - with {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: it seems you don't understand how works `return`. In current code you generate only one post because you use `return` inside `for`-loop and it ends function after first post. If you want to display all posts then you should send all posts to template and use special `for`-loop and `if/else` inside template `{% for ... %} {% if ... %} {% endif %} {% endfor %}`. OR you should first generate string with HTML with all posts and later use `return` with this string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't know how `return` works. It finishs function at once - so in your code you finish function after first `post`.

If you want all post on page then you have to send them all to template and use special `{% for %}`,`{% if/else %}` inside this template

function

```
def posted(request):
    posts = Album.objects.all()
    return render(request, """template""", posts)
```

and template

```
"""
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if forloop.counter % 2 == 0 %}:

         <!-- ... html for even post ... -->

    {% else %}

         <!-- ... html for odd post ... -->

    {% enif %}
{% endfor %}
"""
```

Comment: That's how I wanted to do it, but I didn't know how to use conditions within Django ... Thank you very much!
I will test and come back to tell!

Answer (score 0):

I think that we have to do a major makeover of your code.
First of all, using Django’s the ‘render’ function will make your life A LOT easier. What you need to do first is set your base_dir in settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Now set your templates_dir in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now that you did that, in make a folder called ‘templates’ in your projects base directory. Now, make a file in the ‘templates’ folder called ‘view.html’.
Paste the following css in the new html:

```
<style>
/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
float: left;
width: 50%;
padding: 10px;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
</style>
```

Now, copy all the html from your view into the html file. To make 2 columns, put the html for each column in this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column"
</div>
</div>
```

Whatever html is put in this will become a column that is 50% of the width of the browser window.
But how do you send the information to your template? Modify your view like this:
from django.shortcuts import render

```
def posted(request):
    posts = Album.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'view.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Note that instead of using a for loop in the view, we are moving it to the template.
But how do you divide the posts up?
In the html, you want to use the {% for %} and {% ifequal %} and {% ifnotequal %} tags.
So in the column for items with an even id you'll put:

```
{% for post in posts %}
{% ifequal post.id is divisible by(2) True %}
<div class="container marketing  ">
<div class="row mb-2 " >
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row g-0 border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
        <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">{{ post.title }}</strong>
        <h3 class="mb-0">{{ post.author.get_full_name }}</h3>
        <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ post.created_at|date:'d, M Y'}}</div>
        <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{ post.summary|safe }}</p>
        <a href="/post/{{ post.pk }}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
        <img class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" src="{{post.image.url}}" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/></img>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endifequal %}
```

And for items that the id is odd:

```
{% for post in posts %}
{% ifnotequal post.id is divisible by(2) True %}
<div class="container marketing  ">
<div class="row mb-2 " >
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row g-0 border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
        <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">{{ post.title }}</strong>
        <h3 class="mb-0">{{ post.author.get_full_name }}</h3>
        <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ post.created_at|date:'d, M Y'}}</div>
        <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{ post.summary|safe }}</p>
        <a href="/post/{{ post.pk }}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
        <img class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" src="{{post.image.url}}" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/></img>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endifnotequal %}
```

This combination of css and fully maximizing Django's beatiful template system should solve your problems, and simplify the code.
Also, don't forget to import your model in the view!
Plus, I recommend you get a good book on Django from the library and read through the whole thing; it will help you understand how to maximize Django's functions. Also, w3schools.com is a great resource for css, and simpleisbetterthancomplex.com is greta for Django.
Otherwise, good luck with Django (I just started like 4 months ago btw), and respond if something doesn't work!

Comment: I know its a lot... sry!

Comment: Thanks Kovy Jacob, I don't knew how use conditions in Django... Then I tried render a function with HTML. Now I realize how crazy was that I wrote. rsrsrs.

Comment: Ya! We all make tat mistake tho